# Multipage setup same code basis but different config file

Tags: php, apache

We currently have a mutltisite setup of more than 20 sudomains for customers.
The same codebase is used for all sites, let's just say it is located in the folder `/srv/code`.
Apache's root directory points to it as well.

Now we have to create a folder under `/var/www/subdomain` for each subdomain and put a configuration file called `config.ini` there.

How do I tell Apache now when the PHP script searches for the file `config.ini` that it can find it here: `/var/www/subdomain` ?
And is it the best solution ever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a shared host? If yes, you should first check if a script inside `/srv/code` is allowed to access a file in `/var/www/subdomain`.

You can extract the domain the current script was called via from `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`. You can then use this information to extract the subdomain from it and access the config.ini in the correct directory.

This is probably easier then doing it in Apache.

Comment: No root server, I have full access.

Comment: Then you should be fine with the approach above. Another way of doing something similar would be to symlink your /src/code directory into the subdomain directory and use .htaccess rewriting to access the script.